# /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value while installing h5py

Tags: python-3.x, gcc, pip, redhat, h5py

I'm trying to install on RHLE via pip3 `h5py` but I get through this problem

```
 gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mcpu=power8 -mtune=power8 -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -I/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/include -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mcpu=power8 -mtune=power8 -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DH5_USE_16_API -I./h5py -I/tmp/pip-install-k08hsnjl/h5py/lzf -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/include/python3.6m -c /tmp/pip-install-k08hsnjl/h5py/h5py/defs.c -o build/temp.linux-ppc64le-3.6/tmp/pip-install-k08hsnjl/h5py/h5py/defs.o
    In file included from /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1830:0,
                     from /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12,
                     from /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-k08hsnjl/h5py/h5py/api_compat.h:26,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-k08hsnjl/h5py/h5py/defs.c:642:
    /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
     #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
      ^
    In file included from /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:21:0,
                     from /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-k08hsnjl/h5py/h5py/api_compat.h:26,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-k08hsnjl/h5py/h5py/defs.c:642:
    /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1463:1: warning: ‘_import_array’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
     _import_array(void)
     ^
    gcc -pthread -shared -L/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-rpath,/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64 -Wl,--enable-new-dtags build/temp.linux-ppc64le-3.6/tmp/pip-install-k08hsnjl/h5py/h5py/defs.o -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64 -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-R/opt/local/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-R/usr/local/lib -lhdf5 -lhdf5_hl -lpython3.6m -o build/lib.linux-ppc64le-3.6/h5py/defs.cpython-36m-ppc64le-linux-gnu.so
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.6m.a(Python-ast.o): nella funzione "obj2ast_keyword":
    /home/axyonrl/Python-3.6.9/Python/Python-ast.c:7768:(.text.unlikely+0x608): call to `_Py_keyword' lacks nop, can't restore toc; recompile with -fPIC
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.6m.a(Python-ast.o): nella funzione "obj2ast_comprehension":
    /home/axyonrl/Python-3.6.9/Python/Python-ast.c:7420:(.text.unlikely+0x9f4): call to `_Py_comprehension' lacks nop, can't restore toc; recompile with -fPIC
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.6m.a(Python-ast.o): nella funzione "obj2ast_alias":
    /home/axyonrl/Python-3.6.9/Python/Python-ast.c:7803:(.text.unlikely+0xbec): call to `_Py_alias' lacks nop, can't restore toc; recompile with -fPIC
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.6m.a(Python-ast.o): nella funzione "obj2ast_withitem":
    /home/axyonrl/Python-3.6.9/Python/Python-ast.c:7838:(.text.unlikely+0xdd4): call to `_Py_withitem' lacks nop, can't restore toc; recompile with -fPIC
    /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I tried to do `CFLAGS=--enable-shared pip3 install h5py` and `CFLAGS=-fPIC pip3 install h5py`
but with no success. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: What is "*link finale non riuscito*"? Can you please switch locale to English?

Comment: edited, as the title said it's: final link failed